# Usege of as and like

Tags: word-usage, word-difference, metaphors

What are the differences between of these words?
"As" and "like"

Do you think is this sentence right?

> They are still behaving to me as (or like) child.

Comment: You should probably use  **treating** rather than **behaving to**, and you need the indefinite article **a** before child. Yes, **as** and **like** are interchangeable in this context. Note that we usually expect people to do a little research before posting a question, and quoting that research to explain specifically what they don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question can be interpreted rather broadly, but I'll restrict this answer to the example you provided.

> **As** *preposition*
>   2 Used to indicate by comparison the way that something happens or is done:
>   ‘they can do as they wish’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/as)
>
> **Like** *preposition*
>   1 Having the same characteristics or qualities as; similar to:
>   ‘he used to have a car like mine’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/like)

*As* and *like* are similar terms that set up comparisons, but there are subtle differences. Let's tidy up your example and use both terms in turn:

1. They are still behaving as children.
2. They are still behaving like children.

In #1, *they* could be described as taking on the *role* of children, in the way that actors take on the role of their characters. If *they* were in fact children, the sentence still makes sense; it would carry the meaning that *they* had not yet outgrown the 'childhood phase'.

In #2, the behaviour of *they* and the behaviour of *children* are simply equated. It would be somewhat awkward to use #2 in the case that *they* really were *children* - the comparison becomes trivial (the trivial comparison is between *the behaviour of children* and *the behaviour of children*), and one might imagine the reply, "Well, of course they are!"

As for whether your quoted sentence is grammatically correct, there are several issues.

First, numerical agreement: *they* is plural, so should agree with *children*, not *child*. Nevertheless, *they* has become accepted as a gender-neutral pronoun:

> **they** *pronoun*
>   2 [singular] Used to refer to a person of unspecified gender:
>   ‘ask a friend if they could help’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/they)

There are also issues with "to me", depending on whether you intended to say "towards me" or "this is my opinion", but I'll leave that for another question.